# Monitoring RAM and CPU consumtion of Snakemake

Tags: cpu, benchmarking, ram, snakemake

I want to get CPU and RAM usage of a Snakemake pipeline across time.
I run my pipeline on a slurm managed cluster. I know that Snakemake
include benchmarking functions but they only reports pic consumption.
Ideally, I would like to have an output file looking like this :

```
t  CPU     RAM
1  103.00  32
2  ...     ...
```

Is there any program to do so?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know any program already doing this, but you can monitor the CPU and MEM usage via native unix commmands, [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/56286) gives an answer that could fit your requirements.
Here is a summary of the answer modified for this context:

You can use this bash function

```
logsnakemake() { while sleep 1; do  ps -p $1 -o pcpu= -o pmem= ; done; }
```

You can tweak the frequency of logging by modifying the value of `sleep`.
To log your **snakemake** process with pid=123 just type in the terminal:

```
$ logsnakemake 123 | tee /tmp/pid.log
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found [Syrupy](https://github.com/jeetsukumaran/Syrupy?fbclid=IwAR04RVp8BU99uHx75IlqstsGJQLz2vmpR8yU9i2DGfZhNz3Z_JCntADxUF4) on github : a ps parser in python with a clear documentation.